# Not Able To Connect to Laravel Homestead MySQL Server through PHP Artisan Command but CAN connect through web browser/app

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ssh, homestead

Really weird issue I'm having. First lets start with my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Now, as you can see I'm connecting to localhost, and using port 33060.

If i connect to my web app through my 'blog.app' domain I'm able to connect just fine, and I'm able to pull information from the database just fine. Homestead is set up and provisioned correctly and the domain is being forwarded in the /etc/hosts file.

Now whenever I run the php artisan command on my HOST machine and not inside the vagrant box, i'm getting some connection issues...

I have installed on my machine the newest version of MySQL however I have gone underneath my system preferences and turned it off to avoid conflicts...

In order to test the migration to see if its successful i'm just running migrate:refresh for now.

Here's some screenshots of the errors, and how i have my .env file and database.php file setup.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBvGn.jpg

Don't know if the issue is on my host machine or inside the vagrant box. Should i ALWAYS be running php artisan commands by SSH'ing into the vagrant box? Can i run php artisan on the host machine? I figured you'd be able to.

If additional information is needed please let me know, i'll edit the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior because the ports are different when accessing MySQL from your host machine vs. the VM.

There is a way to setup the port mapping’s so they change depending on where the request is coming from as described in this article
https://medium.com/@morrislaptop/connect-to-laravel-homestead-mysql-from-inside-and-outside-the-host-machine-a117b3ba75f2

Comment: LIFESAVER I TELL YOU! oh my lord. thank you. :D Though i will say that i only changed the 'host' and the 'port' lines within the database.php file and then deleted the host and port from the .env.... i didn't copy and paste the whole code snippet given because it removed some variables set like the engine, and strict variables. So just replace those two lines and you're good.